# Different type in the same variable in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm doing a project and I have a question about SQL.

Requirements ask me to do a table where one variable of it has to be a number between 0 to 10 or a string called "MH" (Honors in another language).

How can I make a variable to do that? It has to be able to have a range 0-10 (qualification) or a "MH" as the best mark that every student can get.

(range 0-10 has to be float because it can exists 4.5 for example)

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: You can't. Either you create a column of type Varchar and convert the values to compare (when applicable) or you create two columns and use one or the other based on the value passed. For the range one you can create a constraint check.

Comment: set 11 as an MH mark

Comment: Store the value as a string, if it needs to contain both numeric and string values.  I would use a string format, such as "00.0000" for all the numbers, so they will sort correctly.

Comment: Because performance for floats is probably better, you may want to use a float (or decimal) as you had originally planned, and present to the users with a view with an if or case statement which returns "MH". 

Better to use two columns and not mix data types, though.